# JSON in Web Service

Tags: java, json, web-services

Is there any limitation on JSON if we want to implement it in web service?

I have a code in Java and try to run in java program-executable. it works.

```
sql = "SELECT attributes FROM common_attr_test";
            stmt = (Statement) conn.createStatement();
            rst = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

            while (rst.next()) {
                 valueAttributes = rst.getString("attributes"); //get value for database                    
            }

              JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(valueAttributes);

              //For Time_Login

             System.out.println("obj is"+obj);
```

The result that I'm getting was :

```
obj is{"1":[{"entry":"3","count":1}],"2":[{"entry":"https://uap.mimos.my/owa","count":1}],"3":[{"entry":"Chrome|Windows NT 6.1","count":1}],"4":[],"7":[{"entry":"1","count":1}],"8":[{"entry":"1","count":1}]}
```

However, when the same code is written in one of the web service function, it did not show the expected result. It stuck at :

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(valueAttributes);
```

with Soap Error:

```
<faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
     <faultstring>org/json/JSONObject</faultstring>
```

Code in web service :

```
sql = "SELECT attributes FROM common_attr_test WHERE uuid='"+uuID+"'";
        stmt = (Statement) conn.createStatement();
        rst = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
while (rst.next()) {
             valueAttributes = rst.getString("attributes"); //get value for database                    
        }

        logWriter("valueAttributes from database : "+valueAttributes);

        //test 9 oct

            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(valueAttributes);
```

Is there any different when we want to implement the code in normal Java program or in web service program? Any dependency?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you are not getting any values from your DB.  Also why are you `looping` and updating `valueAttributes` meaning you are only using the last value

Comment: SOAP is XML over HTTP, unless you are thinking of wrapping your JSON in CDATA.

Comment: in normal java program, the same code is running. only when i put it in we service program it stuck

Comment: Can you post your web-service method? I hope you are not returning JSONObject.

Comment: same as showed above.. i put i answer 2

Comment: You cannot send JSON in a SOAP service unless you wrap it in CDATA etc. You are getting REST and SOAP mixed up. This is why you are seeing this error.

Comment: CDATA? Can you explain more?

I've read in some of the web site and it said that some configuration also need to be done.

FYI, I'm using Axis2 web service.